# Format data before showing on ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a ListAdapter which takes the dates from my SQLite database and displays them all on the list. The thing is, the date is not in human readable format, and I have a helper method to perform the conversion, but how do I implement it on my code?

This is how my code looks like:

```
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { TrackerDbAdapter.KEY_DATE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.row_date };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter history =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.history_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(history);
```

Comment: Not an answer but for improve performance, i think it is better to convert time format when save data to database rather than convert each time you load data from database.

Comment: Not a good idea because I don't want to save dates as "27 July 2011" in the database, but I'd want something like "20110727" (YYYYMMDD) for letting it to be easy to perform comparisons and to uses of other formats too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a custom ListAdapter or custom SimpleCursorAdapter

If you do not need to use a cursor, have a look at this link. http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ It explains how to use an arraylist and custom listAdpater.

You can also do the same with the SimpleCursorAdapter. I was unable to find a good tutorial at this time. I will add to this when I do

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` to attach the formatted data to Views.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder dataBinder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
@Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        ((TextView)view).setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
        return true;
    }
};
simpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(dataBinder)
```

Comment: Where do I place that code exactly? I tried placing it after the SimpleCursorAdapter, but I got some error in the last line that dataBinder isn't the correct argument for setCursorToString.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I"m not sure where to place it in my code. Do I also have to change something from my original code? It's still something to do with the argument in the last line. I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:  Like @nguyendat said, for performance, you could store the formatted date in the database, as well as the un-formatted version, to give you the most flexibility.  If in the same table though, this would violate 2nd normal form because of the redundancy, and you would have to be careful in your code to update all of the data in the row.
To implement this, put your conversion code in your DBAdapter, in the insert command.

Option 2: Create a class for your date

```
public class FormattedDate {
private int oneDate;
public Punch (int unformattedDate) {
    oneDate = unformattedDate;
}  // ends constructor

@Override
public String toString() {
    //put your conversion code here
    return myFormattedDate;
}}
```

This has the added benefit of a proper place to put any other code for comparisons or conversions.

Inside your DBAdapter, change your query to this

```
public ArrayList<FormattedDate> fetchAllItems() {   
    ArrayList<FormattedDate> results = new ArrayList<FormattedDate>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MY_UNFORMATTED_DATE FROM yourTable", null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            results.add( new FormattedDate(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MY_UNFORMATTED_DATE))));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return results;
    }
```

This returns an ArrayList of FormattedDate objects

Finally, this would populate a listview

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_list_view);
ArrayList<FormattedDate> dateArray = mDBHelper.fetchAllItens();
ArrayAdapter<FormattedDate> dateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FormattedDate> (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, dateArray);
setListAdapter(dateAdapter);
```